# .find Error: Object Required

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble using a .find function (I am getting an Object Required error). I am relatively new to VBA and this is the first time I am using the "Option Explicit" in my declarations so I am assuming that it part of my problem (since I have used .find on other worksheets with no errors).

```
'Filter Variables
    Public Filter_Lookup As Integer
    Public Z As Integer
```

^^This is in my 'declarations' to make the variables global

```
'Setting Filter Value
    WBsheet_Main_Ulzee_Encounter_Infringements.Activate
    Filter_Lookup = Range("c10").Value
        Debug.Print Filter_Lookup
```

^^This is in the individual Sub of the same Module. I did not "set" the Z because it is "set" in the .find function??

Below is the actual .find function.

```
    WBsheet_Main_Ulzee_Encounter_Infringements.Activate
    With WBsheet_Main_Ulzee_Encounter_Infringements.Range("a1:a500")
        Set Z = .Find(Filter_Lookup)
            If Not Z Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print Z.Address
                Z.Select
            End If
    End With
```

THANKS for any advice!!

Comment: Show all of the code as a whole. These snippets cannot reflect your problem clearly.

Comment: None of the 2000+ existing questions related to *vba object required* helped?

Comment: You must declare z as a `Range` as Find represents a Range object.

Comment: Ken, There was only one post related to .find & Object Required. @SJR you answered my question!! Thanks so much the code works now

Comment: That error has nothing to do with `.Find` (or `Option Explicit`). You're using the `Set` keyword to assign an `Integer` instead of an object reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer if from @SJR. --> "You must declare z as a Range as Find represents a Range object"